# Guarantees on integrity in Kafka vs ActiveMQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

The information I found comparing Apache Kafka and ActiveMQ (and similar message queuing products) is never clear about the integrity properties of each solution (especially, consistency).

With Kafka you can get the guarantee that no message is lost even in the presence of failures. Do you lose that guarantee using the "LazyPersistence" option?

By "no loss" I mean that the messages would be available to clients, even upon failure after restart - ideally, all messages arriving at the client, in the correct order.

Does ActiveMQ (either "classic" or Artemis) guarantee no loss of messages upon failure? Any configuration options that do give that guarantee? If the answer would differ for "classic" vs Artemis, that would be nice to know.

Comment: By "no loss" I meant that the message would be available to clients, even upon failure after restart - ideally, all messages arriving at the client, in the correct order.

Comment: If the answer would differ for classic vs Artemis, that would be nice to know.

Comment: I think this question should be broken up into two different questions - one about Kafka and one about ActiveMQ. Based on the answers to each you can make the comparison yourself. The problem with your current question is 2-fold. First, it violates the Stack Overflow policy that a question should only contain 1 question. Your questions contains 3 questions. Second, you're unlikely to find someone who's an expert on both Kafka and ActiveMQ so you'll likely get answers from both Kafka and ActiveMQ folks addressing half your question which will make identifying the "correct" answer impossible.

Comment: I see, Justin, you have a point. On the other hand, my question arises because no resource I found let me make the comparison myself; I suspect because so few people know both solutions well. Let me think about splitting it in a useful way such that I still get the answer I would like...

Answer (score 1):

There is no reasonable or practical way to have "no loss of messages" with any solution.

Kafka's approach is to replicate the data once it gets to the server. As @Jonas mentioned there is a total throughput trade-off. Kafka's producers are typically asynchronous out-of-the-box, so it is reasonable to expect that a process (container restart) or network outage would result in observable message loss from the producing application-side. Also, the LazyPersistence can lead to reasonably observable message loss due to process or server-side Kafka failure.

ActiveMQ's approach is to sync data to disk using the OS system call fsync() which is supposed to result in a write to disk. When you combine that with a RAID storage you have the most practical guarantee of data not being lost.

However, there is a alternative pattern that has nothing to do with persistence that can achieve a higher degree of guarantee. This is used by some financial trading systems and defense applications.

Often referred to as 'fanout'. ActiveMQ has a fanout transport included in its client. Works like this:

1. Producer sends message to 3 servers (they should be as isolated and separated from each other as possible).
2. Consumer(s) receive up to 3 messages.
3. First message through "wins" and the consumer app drops the other 2 messages.

With this approach, you can skip persistence altogether, since you have 3 independent routes and the odds of all 3 failing are low. (There are strategies to improve producer-side QOS in the event producer's network is offline).

Consumer has the option of processing first-message (fast) or requiring at least 2 messages to process and validate that the request is legit (secure, but higher latency).

Comment: I understand that you can increase fault tolerance in the client, but my question was regarding guarantees given by the broker software. Thanks for the explanation, I understand the trade-off better now.

Answer (score 0):

> With Kafka, you can get the guarantee that no message is lost, even in the presence of failures; I guess you loose that guarantee using the "LazyPersistence" option, is that correct?

This is a large topic.

> guarantee that no message is lost

This depends on a few things. First, you may configure retention - after a specific period where it is *fine* for you that the messages are lost. You may consider [infinite retention](https://www.confluent.io/blog/infinite-kafka-data-storage-in-confluent-cloud/) but also beware that you have enough storage for that, maybe you need *compaction* of the topic?

> even in the presence of failures; I guess you loose that guarantee using the "LazyPersistence" option, is that correct?

Kafka is a *distributed system*, it is common for distributed system to rely more on *distributed replication* than *synchronous disk writes*. Even if you write *synchronous* to disk - the disk may die and be lost. To what degree you want to use *distributed replication* (e.g. 3 or 6 replicas?) and *synchronous* or *asynchronous* disk writes depends on your requirements - but it also has a *trade off* in *throughput*. E.g. [AWS Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) is a distributed database that use 6 replicas.